# Endpoint 'admin/authenticated' returns 200 success code no matter what and doesn't run code in controller

Tags: node.js, sails.js, passport.js, passport-local

I have a NodeJS back-end API for my platform built on the framework SailsJS.

When the back-end endpoint is hit that checks if the user has been authenticated, I'd like to run some extra checks and maybe some `console.log()`s to debug an issue I'm having.

However, when I go to do this, it looks like I cannot because no matter what code I put at the controller tied to `/admin/authenticated` it just returns a `200` status code with no JSON data **and** any code I put in the controller function does not run! This is baffling me, do not understand how that could possibly happen.

In my `routes.js` folder I have:

```
'GET /admin/authenticated': 'AdminController.isAuthenticated',
```

Original code at the `AdminController` function `isAuthenticated`:

```
isAuthenticated: function (req, res) {
    return res.json(req.user);
},
```

Some new code I've put in there that does NOTHING:

```
isAuthenticated: function (req, res) {
    console.log("Running isAuthenticated.");
    console.log(req.user);
    return res.status(400).json({error: 'Sending back 400 error'});
},
```

Nothing is logged from the `console.log()`s and a 200 success code is sent back, not the 400 error I put in there.

I'm using the Passport authentication system, and think it must have something to do with that.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? This is mystifying.

Comment: HTTP 200 is not a error code, its the success code.

Comment: @JanithKasun sorry that was simply a typo

Comment: Try using `res.status(400).json({ error: 'Sending back 400 error });` to send the code 400

Comment: @JanithKasun issue stays the exact same. Updated the code to that anyways - does look nicer.

Comment: Try with `sails.log.debug()` instead of `console.log()`